# How to disable tramp autosave and backups, but keep other backups/autosave?

Tags: tramp, auto-save, backup

I'd like to disable autosaves and backups when using tramp, because I neither want to save stuff from remote machines nor stuff belonging to root in my backup/autosave directory. How to do that?

I have read the documentation about tramp [autosave and backup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Auto_002dsave-and-Backup.html).

In particular I have read the suggestion

```
(add-to-list 'backup-directory-alist
              (cons tramp-file-name-regexp nil))
```

Unfortunately I fail to grasp if that is valid if `'backup-directory-alist` already contains an entry for my other backup files `(".*" . ,init-backup-directory)`.

Besides disabling backups, disabling autosave would also be nice.